# How to disable the disabling of an android application (which can be done through settings)?

Tags: android

All android apps in settings can be disabled. But I want to make an application which cant be disabled from settings. What can be done for that?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The user should be able to disable every app on android. Unless you've got a custom Android ROM

Comment: ....and no one will install in app or a custom rom where this is possible....

Comment: impossible due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, because if it was possible, everyone would do it, and that would completely nullify the point of letting the user be the sole decision maker about disabling an app.

Comment: If you see, for example, applications in Samsung phones, they cant be disables( like calendar,contacts and all). So this is possible and companies do this.

Comment: @AnunaySharma Independent device manufacturers can do whatever they want for their own preloaded apps.  And customers do complain about the inability to control some of these preloads.  This is a completely different situation than apps downloaded from a store.

Comment: At that point of time i was working at samsung, so I could have handled these cases. And done this.